# PhantomJS screen capture D3.js datamaps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, phantomjs, datamaps

I would like to take screenshots of D3 maps such as [this](https://martingonzalez.net/datamaps-d3-example/) one. 
I am able to take screenshots of the websites with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) and [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js).

```
phantomjs rasterize.js https://martingonzalez.net/datamaps-d3-example/ map_rasterize_1000x500.png 1000px*600px
```

Unfortunately, the arcs are cut off as you can see below.

[image]

Is there a way get the full arcs as well? I would also be able to take images of local HTML files with the D3 maps if that would be more straightforward.

PS I used the example rasterize.js which can be found below.

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size, pageWidth, pageHeight;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    console.log('  image (png/jpg output) examples: "1920px" entire page, window width 1920px');
    console.log('                                   "800px*600px" window, clipped to 800x600');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                           : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    } else if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[3].substr(-2) === "px") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        if (size.length === 2) {
            var pageWidth = parseInt(size[0], 10),
                pageHeight = parseInt(size[1], 10);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        } else {
            console.log("size:", system.args[3]);
            var pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[3], 10),
                pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10); // it's as good an assumption as any
            console.log ("pageHeight:",pageHeight);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        }
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to delay your screenshot capturing logic. As i can see lines are drawn with delay.

Comment: @Observer that would be great. How would I do that?

Comment: please add your phantom.js logic

Comment: @Observer just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this logic:

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
```

To this:

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 5000);
```

It is possible that 5000 milliseconds it is to much, but it is for testing. It is better to know when animation is finished than capture screenshot.